# Как происходит блочное шифрование в RSA

Tags: java, криптография, rsa

Я понимаю, что это разделение текста на блоки, и потом шифрование, для того чтобы буквы не шифровались одними и теми же значениями. Но я не понимаю как именно происходит шифровка, где принимает участие строка переведенная в биты. Буду рад любой помощи. Спасибо!

Comment: Какой ответ вы ожидаете? Есть тонна мануалов с пояснениями, вы думаете тут смогут лучше рассказать?

Comment: @tym32167 Можете поделиться ссылками на лучший по вашему мнению?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

По науке, механизм блочного шифрования называется модой или режимом шифрования (block cipher mode).

1. В самом тупом варианте, когда блоки шифруются раздельно и сцепляются друг с другом as-is называется ECB (Electronic Code Book), обычно он практически не применяется.
2. Наиболее популярной считается мода CBC (Cipher Block Chaining) - сцепление блоков. Иллюстрируется картинкой:
   [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Критически важным параметром для CBC (как впрочем и во многих модах) является IV (инициализирующий вектор) - случайный набор битов/слов совпадающий по длине с блоком.

Все это неплохо разжевано [в статье в Википедии](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A0%D0%B5%D0%B6%D0%B8%D0%BC_%D1%81%D1%86%D0%B5%D0%BF%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8F_%D0%B1%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%B2_%D1%88%D0%B8%D1%84%D1%80%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BA%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B0)